# Remove inline style from body element that is automatically added by WordPress Liveblog

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm using WordPress Liveblog ([see here on Github](https://github.com/Automattic/liveblog)). For some reason `position: relative;` is getting added as an inline style to my body element. e.g. `<body class="blah" style="position: relative;">`

I can't figure out how the inline style is being added. I need to remove it. Hoping somebody has an idea of how this can be done?

Comment: I don't see it in any js in the plugin. Are you sure it's not something else?

Comment: I'm 100% sure because when I deactivate the Liveblog plugin, the style is removed.

Comment: when you inspect with firebug, what file does it tell you it's in?

Comment: It doesn't give a file name. It just says `element.style { position: relative; }`

Comment: what do you need to have it there?

Comment: I need it removed because it is causing the rest of my page to misbehave. For example, I have a footer which is fixed to the bottom of the screen. With `position: relative;` in place on the body tag, my footer floats half way up the page etc etc.

Comment: what happens if you override it with different attribute of the property? using !important. Try body{property:inherit!important}

Comment: thanks for putting me on the right path, do you want to post an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what happens if you override it with different attribute of the property? using !important.

Try `body{property:inherit!important}`

Comment: This worked great! Thank you. I adapted it slightly - `body { position: static !important; }`